# How to make a default:Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a 10 products but I want particular product default on display. Example If type http://localhost/products then product display should be product xyz.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a new boolean column like :default_product, then in the model use a scope like "scope :feature_product, first(:conditions => {:default_product => true})". Then, in the controller, use :feature_product to instead of all by doing Product.feature_product in the index method.

Comment: An idea is to make default_product field type datetime so that last 10 products that are marked as default are shown.

Comment: I am getting this error undefined method `where' for #<Class:0x1059fa0c8>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using REST so in your products controller:

```
def index
    @products = []
    @products << p1 = Product.find_by_name('name')
    @products << p2 = Product.find_by_name('name')
    @products << p3 = Product.find_by_name('name')
end
```